# What dictionary keys to use for UIActivityItemProvider for text plus url?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

To provide different sharing text and urls for different share actions I've created a subclass of UIActivityItemProvider.

It's easy enough just to return different text in

```
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
```

However, if we want to include Text plus a URL, it's not clear. Do we just pass back a string with the URL inside it?

I've seen some code where people pass back a Dictionary, like this for email:

```
 if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
        return @{@"body":self.emailBody, @"url":self.filepath};
    }
```

But what are the right Keys to use for Facebook, Twitter and SMS? Probably "url" for the link, but is it "body" or "text" or what for the text part?

**UPDATE:** 
So for now, I'm passing both an instance of my UIActivityItemProvider and an NSURL to UIActivityViewController like this:

[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[customProvider,url] applicationActivities:nil];

That seems to work. The custom provider supplies the text and the url supplies the link. Not sure if it is any different than just including the link as part of the text though.

Comment: I must say I haven't used this API, but isn't the content returned back to your code, so you can put in whatever makes sense to you?

Comment: Content is not returned to my code if they click Facebook, Twitter, SMS or Email from UIActivityViewController that is presented. At least not as far as I know. Those apps somehow extract what they need from whatever the UIActivityItemProvider provides. It is not well documented.

Comment: Ninety-nine percent of the time we are posting text, images, and urls. Why is it so convoluted? Why does Facebook ignore the `-(id)item` return?